# Using Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint while the camera is moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

want to make a game where there is a 2D ball which moves to the position of the cursor. To get the position of the cursor, I use this code:

```
Vector2 PixelPos = Input.mousePosition;
```

Then to convert the screen position to world position I use this code:

```
Vector2 Pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(PixelPos);
```

The problem is that the main camera move up so that if forces the player to move. But when it move I get some weird movement with the ball.(as the camera is moving up it is always moving the ball)

Is there an alternate way to make this work??

Or more simply can I replace this piece of code:

```
Vector2 Pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(PixelPos);
```

with some other things which does not require a camera to convert the screen positions to world position?

Thanks!

Comment: Please describe the result you want. Are you asking how to move the cursor so that it's in the same world position when the camera moves?

Comment: The camera will move up every seconds...but the ball needs to stay at the cursor position.

Comment: Did you set `PixelPos.z` to your clipping board distance?

Comment: "The camera will move up every seconds...but the ball needs to stay at the cursor position."   Isn't that exactly what is already happening already with `Vector2 Pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(PixelPos);`?

Comment: The game is in 2d and the z axis does not affect the position. The thing is that when the camera is moving up, It is always changing the position where the ball needs to move at. Because I am using this piece of code: `Vector2 Pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(PixelPos);`

Comment: Even in 2d if you do not set up z `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint` gives you position of the camera. That is why your ball moves with camera

Comment: @AliKanat I think Sarwin is using an orthographic camera, so it gives the correct position for x,y at z=0.

Comment: The ball should stay at the cursor position but the way I get the cursor position is by using the camera to convert the screen position to world space position. This is why when the camera is moving up, it is affecting the mouse position.

Comment: @Ruzihm ah thanks i did not know `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint` gives correct result without setting up z when using ortographic camera.

Comment: Is there any other way of converting screen position to world space position without using the camera?

Comment: @Sarwin Yes, it's clear what you already have but you aren't fully explaining the behavior you want. Suppose the ball and the cursor are in the center of the screen + 10 pixels to the right, and the camera moves to the right 10 pixels. Now, the ball is exactly in the center of the screen. Where should the cursor be? Where should the ball go?

Comment: The cursor should remain at the same position and the ball should continue its way to the mouse position. the camera should not affect the cursor position nor the ball position. The cursor position should only be affected by the user when moving the mouse.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want the cursor to be moved only by the player and to be updated relative to world space, not screen space, you need to implement a virtual cursor that exists in world space.

First, create your virtual cursor as a `GameObject`. On `Update` you can update its position with

```
float sensitivity = 1f;
transform.position += sensitivity * new Vector2( 
        Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), 
        Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y")
);

Then, instead of using the camera to find the cursor position, you just check the `transform.position` of that virtual cursor `GameObject`.
```

Second, you'll need to lock the built-in cursor.  You can do that with

```
Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
```

If you need to undo that (for instance, if you bring up a menu, and need to use the regular cursor without moving the virual cursor around), then you can use:

```
Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
```

or, if you need the cursor to stay in the window:

```
Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Confined;
```

---

If you only want to move the ball to the last position clicked/touched then here is an easier solution.

Keep track of the goal position for the ball, and if one has been set yet:

```
private Vector2 moveGoalPos;
private bool moveGoalSet= false;
```

**Only change `moveGoalPos` on frames where the mouse is clicked/the screen is touched.**:

```
bool isTouched;
if (isMouseEnable) {
    isTouched = Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0);
    PixelPos = Input.mousePosition;
} else {
    isTouched = Input.touchCount > 0;
    Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
    PixelPos = touch.position;
}

if (isTouched) {
    moveGoalPos= Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(PixelPos);
    moveGoalSet= true;
}
```

However, on every frame, you'll want to move the ball to the world space `moveGoalPos` (only if a goal has been set):

```
if (moveGoalSet) {
    Vector2 OffsetPos = moveGoalPos + CursorOffSet; 

    GCursor.transform.position = OffsetPos; 
    print(OffsetPos);   
    Vector2 LerpPos = Vector2.Lerp(rb.transform.position, OffsetPos, 0.05f);

    rb.MovePosition(LerpPos);
}
```

When you need to stop the ball from moving to the last touched/clicked position (for instance, if you change or reset a level), you'll need to reset `moveGoalSet`:

```
moveGoalSet = false;
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution it will work for pc but as the game is met for android, I use `Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0); 
                PixelPos = touch.position;`  So is there any way of getting the position of the touch in world position ??

Comment: What happened to `Vector2 PixelPos = Input.mousePosition;`?

Comment: I used it to test if the mechanics was working for pc.. so that I don't have to build the game each time I test it..

Comment: This is the actual code.. responsible for movement:::::  if (!isMouseEnable)
        {
            if (Input.touchCount > 0)
            {
                Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
                PixelPos = touch.position;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            PixelPos = Input.mousePosition;
            //print(PixelPos);
        }

Comment: Vector2 Pos = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(PixelPos);
        Vector2 OffsetPos = Pos + CursorOffSet;
        GCursor.transform.position = OffsetPos;
        print(OffsetPos);

        Vector2 LerpPos = Vector2.Lerp(rb.transform.position, OffsetPos, 0.05f);
        rb.MovePosition(LerpPos);

Comment: You should post another question because that's not the same thing as this question anymore.

Comment: But is there a way to get the touch position in world space position without having to convert??

Comment: Thanks i will use touch phases to move the virtual cursor in diffrent directions.. Thanks again.

Comment: @Sarwin I edited my answer to include how to handle only following where the most recent touch/click occurred instead of always following the cursor as the question explicitly says.  Please accept the answer by clicking on the grey check mark if it helped.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time ... And i will try the soulution you proposed.. Thanks again